# Tons of errors on npm install

Tags: node.js, npm

I have npm version 3.6.0 and node.js version v5.7.1. No matter what packages I try to install I get these error and sometimes the packages install and sometimes they don't. I am not behind a proxy and I turned off my virus protection and am running cmd as Administrator and am on a fresh install of windows 10. Any help would be appreciated

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v5.7.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.6.0

npm ERR! Callback called more than once.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\remojr76\Desktop\Development\web-template - Copy\npm-debug.log
```

Comment: Please include the following file with any support request: C:\Users\remojr76\Desktop\Development\web-template - Copy\npm-debug.log